# How and where to register an email account to be used for sending emails from an app to the owner of the device?

Tags: android

I have written an (android) app which can send emails to the user of the device. The user's gmail account is read from the device, and is used both as the email's sender and receiver address. The emails are currently sent via the gmail smtp server, via an email account registered by me (with a name corresponding to the name of the app). The App programmatically logs into my account, with the proper password, and sends the email to the user's account. It worked for a short time.  Then gmail seemed to react on the fact that this email account was being logged into from various parts of the world (i.e. from my App used by various/different customers), and they suspected that the account was being hijacked. And they forced me to change the password. So this setup no longer seems to be working.

So my question is:
HOW can this be achieved?
Using another email account to send the emails through?
HOW?  WHERE?
Or is there another way to use the gmail smtp server for this purpose?

Regards, Terje

Answer (score 0):

**Why :** 
Explain to us why you want to send an email on the very same device you are sending the mail from...Someone might give you a better solution for what you are trying to achieve.

**Answer :** 
The best most reliable way to achieve what you want to do is to set up your own web server(cheapest one from the cheapest web hosting company will work) which will come with your own preconfigured smtp service.

Then call a webservice on this server that will send the email from the server.

The webservice can be as simple as a php script with a single line :

```
<?php
     $to      = 'personne@example.com';
     $subject = 'subject';
     $message = 'Hello !';
     $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
     'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n";

     mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 ?>
```

Of course you will get the variables from the GET or POST variable that you will send from your Android application.

You can make this very secure or very loose as I did above and if you ever change your smtp, you will only need to change it once on the webserver and all your installed app will automatically be able to continue send emails to your users.

Comment: Thank you, Yahel. This is the default way of sending emails from the app. Alternatively, the user can configure his own sender-, receiver-. and smtp host. But the default ensures that he gets the emails to his own account, in the simplest way. I know that I can set up my own web server to do this, but I was hoping to avoid it.

Comment: Surely there must be some smtp servers somewhere which will accept such use? An smtp server only using port 25 (with no password) may also be acceptable.

Comment: Trying to go the smtp server way is going the hard way : A lot, if not most of people behind wifi will not be able to send email via the port 25. Most FAI block this port because of spammers using zombie machines to send their junk mails. I believe we will see the same type of blocking for mobile device in the future as they are prone to malware as well.